# PIP Showing Errors While Trying to Install Packages

Tags: python, pip

I installed the latest version of Python, on my system (3.10), and pip shows errors when I try to install a python package. For example, when I install Pygame, I get these errors:

```
 Path for FREETYPE not found.
    ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
```

and:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/b8/b110cdea95452f8f9f9e79d02062fdccaebfd808a
667d6d9a805ca8d222a/pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz#sha256=2050c68ff6eba1f801efc14fd1f805aaa3a94936c80ed6725b64a75ca1bce
66f (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
 egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

and it tries to install previous versions. I am on a Windows 11 PC. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Have you added python to path?
If you have not added Python to path,
see this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTUlp6L2zkw

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Python is added to path. I had checked the 'Add Python to Path' checkbox in the installer.